# Prove if $n$ is an odd integer, then $3n$ is odd.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So far I have:

Assume $n$ is odd, $n  = 2k+1$ for some integer $k$.

Then\begin{align}3n&= 3(2k+1)\\
&= 6k + 3\end{align}

I'm unsure where to go from here.

Comment: Can you find an integer $z$ such that your $3k$ is $3z+1$?

Comment: $6k$ is even.  Add $3$ to it gives....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the fact that $6k+3=2(3k+1)+1$.

Comment: How does the 2(3+1)+1  help?

Comment: Because the odd integers are precisely those that can be written as $2N+1$.

Comment: and so that means I can then write 2N + 1 where the N is actually the 3k + 1 ,,,which means its odd and the proof is true?

Comment: A proof is neither true nor false. But if you add that $6k+3=2(2k+1)+1$, then it will be a *correct* proof.

Answer (score 2):

Since $2n$ is even, we have $3n=2n+n$ as a sum of an odd number and an even number, which is obviously odd.

Answer (score 1):

Take $$n=2k+1$$ this is an odd number, then $$3(2k+1)=6k+3=(6k+2)+1$$ this is also an odd number.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ be odd, so $n = 2m + 1$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. We have:
\begin{align*}
3n = 3(2m+1) = 6m + 3 = 2(3m + 1) + 1,
\end{align*}
where $3m + 1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ by closure. Let $z = 3m + 1$, so we have
\begin{align*}
3n = 2z + 1.
\end{align*}
Thus, $3n$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

$6k + 3$ can be written as $6k + 2 + 1$, now factoring we get $2(3k+1) + 1$, let $(3k+1) = A$, then $2A + 1$ is odd. in general, multiplying an odd integer with an odd integer always yields an odd integer. It is a good idea to prove it, you can also prove it with induction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n$ be an odd integer. 
Then $3n$ is the product of two odd integers, and thus odd.